# Can not load X11 Library in ghc 6.12.3

Tags: haskell, osx-lion, x11

OS: OS X Mountain Lion
Platform: ghc 6.12.3

I am having trouble using the X11 1.6.0 Library. When i compile my files i get this error.

`Loading package X11-1.6.0 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: Xext (dlopen(libXext.dylib, 9): image not found)`

I have searched all over the internet but i can't find a solution. I have X11 installed and also made a symlink to the /usr folder because it installed it by default in /opt

Comment: The installer already puts symlinks at /usr/X11 and /usr/X11R6 to /opt/X11.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using 6.12.3 and not one of the newer ghc-7.x (7.4.2, or nowadays, 7.6.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [our discussion on github](https://github.com/haskell-pkg-janitors/X11/issues/14), he needed to direct `dyld` to the location of `libXext.dylib`.